# How do I check if vector<bool> is actually a vector of bits and not bytes?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, boolean, bit

I need to store a dynamic array of bits.
[The C++ reference page on vector< bool >](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) has the following information:

> The storage is not necessarily an array of `bool` values, but the library implementation may optimize storage so that each value is stored in a single bit.

How do I make sure that my program that uses `vector<bool>` does in fact store bits in a vector instead of boolean values (bytes)?

Comment: Is `std::bitset` not an option?

Comment: It generally does, no need to worry.

Comment: I think the point here is that it's implementation dependent and encapsulated so you don't have to know. If you care that much, it may be better to find another way - such as `std::bitset`

Comment: I would not use `vector<bool>`. It causes much pain in general, so I hope people would stop using it so we could deprecate the specialization... Use dynamic bit-set from boost.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is specified for the times when you don't actually care about how it's stored. If you really do need to know, it's not an appropriate container. P.S. use cppreference.com instead of cplusplus.com.

Comment: The problem with std::bitset is that it's not dynamic. I need to know the size of the bitset beforehand.

Comment: There is [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) to use if you really want to be sure, but any mainstream compiler you use will have this space optimization.

Comment: Premature optimization. Save some time, use std::vector<bool> and stop worrying about irrelevancies. Can you say why you need to "make sure"?

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to do that. Instead, use `boost::dynamic_bitset` which clearly indicates what you actually want. The `vector<bool>` optimization actually creates a number of possibilities for bugs, for example when using iterators (because it usually returns a proxy object).

Comment: Exactly. The link in my answer contains some more information on the downsides of `vector<bool>`.

Comment: Although this answer contains good advice, it doesn't actually *answer the question*. A valid answer to this question should either explain how to discover the requested implementation detail, or tell why such an explanation would be impossible to provide. Once that's covered, *then* go into advice on why the answer shouldn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always look into the header files that come with your compiler. Since STL containers are almost exclusively template classes, most if not all parts of the implementation will be visible in the headers.

Maybe looking at a `vector` object in a debugger can also be helpful.

Note: You should also be aware that `vector<bool>` is meanwhile rather frowned upon by the C++ community, and that this optimization is for size, not for speed:

https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to check this at compile time, by checking the return type of the non-const version of `vector<bool>::operator[]`: An implementation that stores its values as bits will have to return a proxy reference class rather than a `bool&`.

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing to check here at all. The specialization of `vector<bool>` to store bits instead of larger objects is required by the standard. §23.2.5: "To optimize space allocation, a specialization of vector for bool elements is provided:".

I suppose from some viewpoint, what you've quoted is at least sort of correct. Since there's essentially nobody to certify conformance of a compiler, and essentially no compiler that even attempts to fulfill all conformance requirements, a compiler *could* choose to ignore this requirement as well.

I don't know of any compiler that does so though -- and if anybody did, I'd guess it would probably be pretty well known. There have been pretty heated discussions at times about removing the `vector<bool>` specialization, so if somebody had real-life examples of how much better (or worse) that made things, I suspect we'd have heard about it.

Edit: In C++11, the requirements for `std::vector<bool>` have been moved to §23.3.7. More importantly, the wording has been changed, to specify that a packed representation where each `bool` is stored as a single bit instead of a contiguous allocation of `bool` values is now only a recommendation.

At least IMO, this makes little *real* difference. As far as I know, all real implementations still use a packed representation, so even though packed storage is no longer theoretically guaranteed, it happens in practice anyway.

Comment: Actually, paragraph 3 says: _A space-optimized representation of bits is recommended_. Not quite a requirement.

Comment: @jogojapan: That was added in C++11. That wasn't present in C++03 (which was what I was actually quoting). In any case, I don't know of an implementation that uses a non-bitwise implementation; unless one exists, your point is pretty much moot anyway.

Comment: Right, I wasn't aware of the C++03/11 difference there. In any case, I think it's useful to make correct statements in SO answers, even if certain aspects are moot.

Comment: @jogojapan: I believe it *is* correct as stated. The only part that's open to question is whether the change in C++11 is enough to merit updating the answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Create a huge `vector<bool>` and look at the memory usage of the program.

Or simply check out the source code - you can peek at the `vector` header.

Comment: why the downvotes? This seems to answers the question. Though I agree that the other answers are better and using `vector<bool>` should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This program kind of prooves it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void showSize() {
    std::vector<T> myvec;
    size_t capacity = myvec.capacity();
    std::cout << "capacity: " << myvec.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size: " << myvec.size() << std::endl;
    while (myvec.capacity() < 1024) {
        while (myvec.capacity() == capacity) {
            myvec.push_back(T());
        }
        capacity = myvec.capacity();
        std::cout << "capacity: " << myvec.capacity() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "size: " << myvec.size() << std::endl;
    }

}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*********************" << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Booleans: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    showSize<bool>();
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*********************" << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Chars: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    showSize<char>();
}
```

output:

```
*********************

Booleans: 

capacity: 0
size: 0
capacity: 64
size: 1
capacity: 128
size: 65
capacity: 256
size: 129
capacity: 512
size: 257
capacity: 1024
size: 513


*********************

Chars: 

capacity: 0
size: 0
capacity: 1
size: 1
capacity: 2
size: 2
capacity: 4
size: 3
capacity: 8
size: 5
capacity: 16
size: 9
capacity: 32
size: 17
capacity: 64
size: 33
capacity: 128
size: 65
capacity: 256
size: 129
capacity: 512
size: 257
capacity: 1024
size: 513
```

So the key is that the capacity for bools increases 64 entries at a time (size of int or my machine). This hints that it's just reserving just 8 bytes at a time.